# Cookies are not passed to the next request for a domain(Firefox)

Tags: firefox, cookies

For authenticating one product it needs to set some cookies. But the cookies are not getting set up. We collected the trace using fiddler. We can see that cookies are available in the response but some how next request is not carrying those cookies.

- No proxies for firefox.
- We even added the fqdn in trusted site list.
- Cookies are enabled.

We collected fiddler trace, the response says that it is adding the cookie but the next request does not have those cookies.

Appreciate any help for narrowing down the issue.
FiddlerTrace-Screenshot1

[image]

Comment: a) Is the next request to the same domain?

Comment: I don't have enough points to add multiple screenshots, so could not add the second sreenshot where next request does not have cookie set.

Comment: Yes, next request is to the same domain.

Comment: Can you check if the cookie is available on the browser? You can do this by checking firebug? Also does it work on Chrome?

Comment: I also would like to clarify that, the issue is NOT that the cookies are not getting set at all. For example, if servername  is abc.xyx.com and we set some cookies for .abc.xy.com the cookies are getting set. But when we try to set for .xyx.com it does not.

Comment: Jerome, No cookies are not available in the browser. We could not try in other browsers because the customer we are working with can not install any other browser.

Comment: This does not seem to be an issue with the browser, because same behavior is observed for IE as-well. It might be something related to the system but don't have any clue to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

We asked customer to check the system why the browser does not accept the cookies for .xyx.com. It took sometime and they could not figure out why.

So to make the product work we changed the cookie to create for .abc.xyx.com. This resolved the issue.